# Code Signed application won't run

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, mac-app-store

I'm trying to code sign - with a developper provisioning profile that includes my machine UUID - my app.  So far so good, I followed the procedure on the Developer Certificate Utility and created all the necessary certificates and profiles for both development and production (just like on iOS).

Problem is: as soon as I code sign my application for Debug (or Release, for that matter) configuration, I get this weird limbo state when I try to run the app: no error message, just a spinning activity indicator in the Log navigator and everything behaving just as if the app was running normally. But it does not show up in the dock, show no warning, nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

(Using Xcode 4,1).

[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT:** 
Ok, I took my project and rebuilt it on another mac starting from scratch. Clearly, I'm doing something wrong since it doesn't work there either.
So, the exact procedure I followed:
1- Create a certificate
2- Drag and drop the certificate in the Keychain

3- Add device's UDID to the portal
4- Create a provisionning profile
5- Open it (adds it to System Preferences)
6- Drag it in Xcode's organizer

7- In my Target's build settings, set the Code Signing Identity to the Mac Dev identity I just added.

And boom, I compile it and it doesn't load. If I archive it and share it as an application (signed with my development certificate) it bounces in the dock and disapears.
So... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by upgrading to 10.7.2 (beta). Why? That's still under non disclosure agreement.

Edit: Also, removing the directory named after my app in my ~/Library/Containers/ was necessary to build with sandboxing on and fix the following crash reported in system.log:

```
taskgated-helper(555) deny file-read-metadata /private/var/db/DetachedSignatures
taskgated-helper(555) deny file-read-data /private/var/db/DetachedSignatures
sandboxd[556] ([555]): taskgated-helper(555) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ocspd
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got same problem. But reason was another - i just forgot to instal profile to system.